# how to convert curl example to Pycurl

Tags: python, api, curl, pycurl

PS - No I am not going to use python requests, cause it does not help creating readable streams of the file.

```
curl -i -H "Authorization":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTQyNjcwNTY4NiwiaWF0IjoxNDI2NzAyMDg2fQ.eyJpZCI6MTc3fQ.yBwLFez2RnxTojLniL8YLItWVvBb90HF_yfhcsyg3lY" \
    -F user_data='{"user data": {"preferred_city":"Newyork","within_radious":"5"}}' \
    -F uploaded_documents=@mydocument.pdf \
    http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/city
```

I am trying to send both file and a json data in pycurl post method.
I am succesful in sending file alone only.
I found above example to send file and data in same api but not able to convert it to pycurl systax properly.
Can anyone please convert it to pycurl type code work?

Comment: Is this an appropriate gesture to vote down without explaining your intention?

Comment: Unfortunately happens all the time.

Comment: Not answering the exact question, but [this service](https://curl.trillworks.com/) seems to be able to generate a Python requests version of it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()      
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/city")
c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTQyNjcwNTY4NiwiaWF0IjoxNDI2NzAyMDg2fQ.eyJpZCI6MTc3fQ.yBwLFez2RnxTojLniL8YLItWVvBb90HF_yfhcsyg3lY"'])
data = json.dumps({"user data": {"preferred_city":"Newyork","within_radious":"5"}})
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS,data)
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, [("uploaded_documents", (c.FORM_FILE, "mydocument.pdf"))])
c.perform()
c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package - `http_pycurl`.

The API it exposes is similar to the requests.

How to install

```sh
pip install http_pycurl
```

Specific usage is [here](https://github.com/pythonqi/http_pycurl).